# mysql support to xquery?

Tags: mysql, xquery

does mysql supports xquery? if yes then which version?

Comment: has anything changed?  question is nine years old..

Answer (score 1):

The following mysql versions support xquery

```
* MySQL Enterprise 5.0.x
```

Comment: Didn't know MS SQL Server 2005 was a version of MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't at the moment, and it doesn't appear to be in the roadmap out to 6.0.  There is some [support for XML](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/xml-functions.html)<sup>*</sup>.

There are third-party providers though, e.g. [Stylus Studio](http://www.stylusstudio.com/mysql.html), [XQuery](http://www.xquery.com/products/factsheet.html).

<sup>*</sup>*The original link has broken due to a MySQL documentation update.*

Answer (score 0):

Zorba XQuery processor has a JDBC connector, you can check it out at http://www.zorba-xquery.com/html/entry/2013/01/23/Zorba_Hermes
I works great with MySQL.